# Awk command to left/right outer join 2 files

Tags: awk

File1 contains 2 rows :

```
/home/asingh549/cleanup,8  
/home/vbhat94/test_bkup,8
```

File2 contains 3 rows :

```
/home/asingh549/cleanup,7  
/home/vbhat94/test_bkup,7  
/home/asingh699/sample/adam,1
```

Expected output :

```
/home/asingh549/cleanup,8  
/home/vbhat94/test_bkup,8  
/home/asingh699/sample/adam,1
```

I tried -

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next} {print $1 FS a[$1] }' File1 File2
```

but I get below output -

```
/home/asingh549/cleanup,8  
/home/vbhat94/test_bkup,8 
/home/asingh699/sample/adam,
```

The 3rd line of the output is missing number 1 after the comma.
Could someone please advice how can I get the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this `awk` solution:

```bash
awk '
BEGIN {FS=OFS=","}
FNR == NR {
   map[$1] = $2
   next
}
$1 in map {
   $2 = map[$1]
}
1' file1 file2

/home/asingh549/cleanup,8
/home/vbhat94/test_bkup,8
/home/asingh699/sample/adam,1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code might be amoleriated to get desired output as follows

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next} {print $1 FS (($1 in a)?a[$1]:$2) }' File1 File2
```

then output changes to

```
/home/asingh549/cleanup,8
/home/vbhat94/test_bkup,8
/home/asingh699/sample/adam,1
```

Explanation: I use so-called ternary operator *condition*`?`*valueiftrue*`:`*valueiffalse*, check `$1 in a` is check if array `a` has given key.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 0):

If this is the wrong answer, I apologise in advance, however...

```
cat file1 > file3
sed -n '3p' file2 >> file3
```

If you need to know how to do this with variable line numbers in future, than you can use '$p' in order to always print the last line of a file, even when you don't know what its' number is.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> {m,g}awk -F, 'NR==FNR ? _*(___[$!_]=$_) : \
>               $!NF = _<(__=___[$!_]) ? __ : $_' f1.txt f2.txt
> ```

```
/home/asingh549/cleanup,8  
/home/vbhat94/test_bkup,8
/home/asingh699/sample/adam,1
```